# How to remove this light box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

How do we change out this light? Can we just knock out the sides and then repair the ceiling? or is it possible that there is wiring in the sides? We want to install a light that is flush with ceiling.

(Above bathroom sink for reference)

Thanks!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite see what's going on with that fixture.  However it looks like 48" fluorescent, so there must be a way to get up in there and replace the bulbs.  There are sometimes latches that lets the whole diffuser and frame swing down.

Other times the diffuser simply lifts upward (held in place by gravity). That allows you to tilt it, shove it sideways a bit into some void space, enough to then tilt the other end downward through the square hole.

That diffuser looks like it's just setting on some quarter-round that someone nailed into the corners.  In that case remove the end quarter-rounds and tip out as I described above.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a fixture.  The OP says "light box" which leads me to believe it may be some kind of light tube, i.e. skylight?